# Communication - Child component with Multiple parent component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

In my app there are multiple parent component, which has table component as child component, I pass all the parameters at the start,when i click on sorting it goes to parent component(now its done by `@Output`), it brings the data from the service(which is defined in parents since all parent bring data from different service) and then pass the data to child by `viewChild` reference of the Table class and calling a method listen in `tablecomponent` class when we have sorted data from backend.

i tried below approaches:-

shared service approach, from the child i was not able to determine which parent should be called.

Behaviour subject:- Output is subscribed from all the parents, so when an output is emitted it goes in all parents.

```
 @ViewChild('mainTable') mainTable: TableComponent;

callChildren(){
  this.mainTable.listenSort(this.rows);
}
```

Can any one suggest me a clear approach for this problem?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: How do you have multiple parent components?, a parent component may have more than one children but how does it work the other way around?

Comment: I have shared component Table Component which i use inside all my pages for showing table, so table component will be a child component and there are many parents to this child component.

Comment: You can output from your child with an unique ID, and filter it in your parent, but i would suggest you to emit a BehaviorSubject with an unique ID which refers to the child component with a ShareReplay operator

Comment: But every parent has It's own table component, they don't share it. Its a normal parent-child relation

Comment: ok, can you suggest how i can not use the below approach and create a shared service which just calls the parent and pass back the data to table component? 

@ViewChild('mainTable') mainTable: TableComponent;

callChildren(){
  this.mainTable.listenSort(this.rows);
}

Answer (score 1):

you should use event emitter, to communicate with parent, so that you will catch event from parent component only. if you want to use service then you need to create saperate instance of service from each parent components.

Comment: yes, i did the same. I created hierarchical injector service and provided in the components as diffrent level, Thanks Everyone my problem is solved.